# Create flag indicating if year variable is in the range of start:end variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 3 date variables: `year`, `start`, `end`.

```
test <- data.table(year=2001:2003,start=c(2003,2002,2000),end=c(2003,2004,2002),x_desired=c(F,T,F))
```

O want to create a new variable `x`, indicating, for each row, if `year` is in the range defined by `start` and `end`. The correct desired result is in the variable `x_desired`.

I imagined this could be done with:

```
test[,x:=(year %in% start:end)]
```

but the result is clearly not correct. I wanted the ranges to be defined row-by-row, but don't know how to express that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach

```
#first, create a x-column with all FALSE
DT[, x := FALSE ]
#update the x-column subset where year is between start and end to TRUE
DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE]
```

Should run fast... Benchmarks will follow soon

## update: benchmarks on a data.table of 1M rows

```
n = 1000000
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(year =sample( 2001:2003, n, replace = TRUE),
                 start=sample( c(2003,2002,2000), n, replace = TRUE),
                 end  =sample( c(2003,2004,2002), n, replace = TRUE) )

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( 
  wimpel = {
    DT <- copy(dt) 
    DT[, x := FALSE ]
    DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE] 
    },
  akrun_nrow = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    DT[, x := between(year, start, end), 1:nrow(DT)]
    },
  akrun_map = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    DT[, x := unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = between, unname(.SD)))), .SDcols = year:end]
    },
  akrun_pmap = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    DT[, x := purrr::pmap_lgl(.SD[, .(x = year, left = start, right = end)], between)]
    },
  markus = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    DT[, col := mapply(between, year, start, end)]
  },
  times = 3
  )
```

**results**

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
     wimpel   29.98388   30.41861   48.98399   30.85333   58.48404   86.11475     3
 akrun_nrow 2741.35268 2755.01860 2944.58975 2768.68453 3046.20829 3323.73206     3
  akrun_map 3673.21253 3683.22849 3711.51209 3693.24446 3730.66188 3768.07929     3
 akrun_pmap 3281.13335 3291.04689 3406.46131 3300.96043 3469.12528 3637.29013     3
     markus 3408.07869 3569.33044 3670.68141 3730.58219 3801.98277 3873.38334     3
```

There seems to be a clear winner.. but perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: @akrun (and markus): I've learned a **lot** from your answers the last years... Since my answer benchmarks so much faster: Am I missing something, or have I finally figured something out that is actually fast? ;-)

Comment: I upvoted and feel happy I left that answer as a comment only ;)

Comment: amazing, @Wimpel, your option ran in 5min (previous code was running for 2hrs when I killed the process). I switched the answer for this one because of the performance gain. Tks akrun, markus and Wimpel.

Comment: millliseconds is not any benchmark, try to get scale that will take at least a second

Answer (score 4):

another way

```r
set(DT, NULL, "x", between(DT$year, DT$start, DT$end))
```

benchmark

```r
library(data.table)
setDTthreads(40L)
n = 1e9
set.seed(123)
DT = data.table(year =sample( 2001:2003, n, replace = TRUE),
                start=sample( c(2003,2002,2000), n, replace = TRUE),
                end  =sample( c(2003,2004,2002), n, replace = TRUE) )
d = copy(DT)

system.time({DT[, x := FALSE ]; DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE]})
system.time(set(d, NULL, "x", between(DT$year, DT$start, DT$end)))

all.equal(d, DT)
```

timings

```
1e6

> system.time({DT[, x := FALSE ]; DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE]})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.433   0.056   0.053 
> system.time(set(d, NULL, "x", between(DT$year, DT$start, DT$end)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.152   0.000   0.025 

1e8

> system.time({DT[, x := FALSE ]; DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE]})
   user  system elapsed 
  3.811   1.889   3.061 
> system.time(set(d, NULL, "x", between(DT$year, DT$start, DT$end)))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.650   1.112   2.132 

1e9

> system.time({DT[, x := FALSE ]; DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE]})
   user  system elapsed 
 32.073  32.600  27.347 
> system.time(set(d, NULL, "x", between(DT$year, DT$start, DT$end)))
   user  system elapsed 
 21.798   8.517  18.248
```

Comment: Never used `set` like this before.. nice to know!

Answer (score 2):

An option is `between`

```
test[, x := between(year, start, end), 1:nrow(test)]
test
#   year start  end x_desired     x
#1: 2001  2003 2003     FALSE FALSE
#2: 2002  2002 2004      TRUE  TRUE
#3: 2003  2000 2002     FALSE FALSE
```

---

```
test[, x := year >= start & year <= end]
```

---

Or another option is `Map`

```
test[, x := unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = between, unname(.SD)))), .SDcols = year:end]
```

---

Or with `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
test[, x := pmap_lgl(.SD[, .(x = year, left = start, right = end)], between)]
```

#### Benchmarks

Added benchmarks on the new option (using the same dataset as @Wimpel's big data)

```
microbenchmark(

 wimpel = {
    DT <- copy(dt) 
    DT[, x := FALSE ]
    DT[ year %between% list(start,end), x := TRUE] 
    },

    akrun = {
    DT <- copy(dt)
    DT[, x := year >= start & year <= end]
    }, times = 3)
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# wimpel 23.25196 40.72112 49.29130 58.19027 62.31098 66.43168     3
#  akrun 19.56071 22.04272 22.96553 24.52473 24.66793 24.81114     3
```

Comment: any thoughts on the performance of the above options? My actual dataset is 900million rows (I am running the 1st option now).

Comment: my full workflow if: start with a 20 million observations dataset, with start and end years. Expand each observation to represent the possible 40 years in the dataset (expand grid 20mm dataset with years:1980:2019). Then compute x.

Comment: @LucasMation  All of these are working on row by row, haven't benchmarked it.  If you can subset the data and check the benchmarks on each method before working on the full data. would be useful

Comment: Another option would be `test[, col := mapply(between, year, start, end)]`

Comment: is `1:nrow(test)` necessary? `between` is vectorized